# Concise method to pass a function on multiple but not all data frames in the global enviroment?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have some rather large data frames and the RAM on my machine cannot process a request/ function with the size of a combined data frame. For this reason they are in the global environment by year. Currently I'm processing the same functions for all of the data frames which works but wondering if there is a more concise method. If I have data frames: CY_19, CY_20, CY_21, df1, df2; in the global environment I have been doing the code below:

```
df_21 <- df_21[(df_21$x=='N'),]
df_20 <- df_20[(df_20$x=='N'),]
df_19 <- df_19[(df_19$x=='N'),]
df_19 <- df_19[(df_19$y=='No'),]
df_20 <- df_20[(df_20$y=='No'),]
df_21 <- df_21[(df_21$y=='No'),]
```

I also run functions:

```
lines_needed <- function(a, b, c, d, e, f){
  CY19 <- a[grep("txt",b, ignore.case = T),]
  CY20 <- c[grep("txt",d, ignore.case = T),]
  CY21 <- e[grep("txt",f, ignore.case = T),]
  CY.all <- rbind(CY19, CY20)
  CY.all <- rbind(CY.all, CY21)
  return(CY.all)
}
Combined_df <- lines_needed(CY_19, CY_19$z, CY_20, CY_20$z, CY_21, CY_21$z)
```

Is there a more concise way of doing this as well?

Thank you community for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over a character vector of the data frame names, use `get` to retrieve each data frame from its name and `assign` or `rbind` the result.  We used `ls` to get a character vector of their names but if you have very similar names that you want to exclude either improve the regular expressions or replace ls(...) with the explicit character vector of their names.

```
nms <- ls(pattern = "^df_")  # c("df_19", "df_20", "df_21")
Sub1 <- function(df) subset(df, x == "N" & y == "No")
for(nm in nms) assign(nm, Sub1(get(nm)))

nms <- ls(pattern = "^CY_")  # c("CY_19", "CY_20", "CY_21")
Sub2 <- function(df) subset(df, grepl("txt", z, ignore.case = TRUE))
combined_df <- do.call("rbind", lapply(nms, function(nm) Sub2(get(nm))))
```

Comment: Thank you this is great information. I do have one question, as I've never seen this before. What is the use of  caret in the quotes? You have couple `"^"` and feel this may have great utility but would like to understand. Is this the same as `c()`? The google results where not fruitful due to the quotations changing the search to require that value and typing it out had no good results.

Comment: `ls(pattern = "...")` returns a character vector of the names of all objects 
in your workspace for which the names match the indicated regular expression.  In a regular expression ^ means *start of string* so only df_ at the start of a name is matched. See `help("regex", "base")` for more information on regular expressions in R and  also see https://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score -1):

You are not approaching this right. Your life would be much easier if instead of many `data.frame`'s you created a single list of `data.frame`s and then use `lapply`.